# Symfony2 Form DateTime return Error

Tags: forms, datetime, symfony

in my entity i have set this

```
public function setExpiry(\DateTime $expiry = null)
    {
        $this->expiry = $expiry;
    }
```

in formType i have set this

```
$builder->add('expiry', 'choice', array(
            'choices'   => array(
date ("Y-m-d H:i:s",mktime(date('H'),date('i'),date('s'),date('m'),date('d')
+3,date('Y'))) => '3 days',

            ));
```

but when submit, return this error

```
::setExpiry() must be an instance of DateTime, string given,
```

i have understand that "string given" but how i can convert in
datatime object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
new DateTime('@'.strtotime("+3 day")) => '3 days'
```